# How to get width of a parent div and based on do further operations in angular2

Tags: angular

Here, I want to get width of `#divToMeasure` and then based on this, need to do further operations.
Please, help me to fix this code and better approach or suggestion are always welcomed.

### abc-component.html

```
<div #parentdiv class="col-xs-12 rmpm" style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
        <div #divToMeasure class="col-xs-12 rmpm"  [style.width.px]="parentdiv.offsetWidth">  <---get this 'width' in 'px'  
        </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngFor ='let dta of data; let i = index' [ngStyle]="{'width':WIDTH}">
         abc
        </div>
```

### abc.component.ts

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
WIDTH: any

ngOnInit(){

// need to get the width of #divToMeasure 
let divToMeasureWidth = __________; <-------how to get that

this.WIDTH = (divToMeasureWidth / this.data.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

`abc.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    
 @Component({templateUrl: './abc-component.html'})
  export class AbcComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('divToMeasure') divToMeasureElement: ElementRef;
    
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      let divToMeasureWidth = this.divToMeasureElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks,--- this.divToMeasureElement.nativeElement.style.width----- also works. Can you please suggest any better way to perform above task.

Comment: What above task? Get the div's width? If so, I believe this is the best approach.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr Also, `this.divToMeasureElement.nativeElement.style.width` doesn't work as you would seem to want it to(based on your question). If an element doesn't have a width applied to it via a style tag or css, it will return empty and not the actual width of the element. You can see this in your dev tools on this page: `document.getElementsByClassName('_full')[0].style.width` vs. `document.getElementsByClassName('_full')[0].offsetWidth`

Comment: I have applied like above [style.width.px]="parentdiv.offsetWidth" and for this, --- this.divToMeasureElement.nativeElement.style.width----- is working but width is in 'px'.